# Exception in Angularjs during Webservice Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, web-services, dom

I am getting following error while calling a webservice using angularjs
using the following method.

```
 $http({
 url     : 'http://localhost:8080/dummy',
 method  : 'POST',
 data    : {'id':'1','name':'test'}, 
 headers : {'id': '1',
            'token': '34343ggfgf4444',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
           })

Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12
Error: An invalid or illegal string was specified.
    at http:localhost:8080/lib/angular/angular.js:8054:17
    at forEach (http:localhost:8080/test/lib/angular/angular.js:329:20)
    at http:localhost:8080/test/lib/angular/angular.js:8052:7
    at sendReq (http:localhost:8080/test/lib/angular/angular.js:7911:9)
    at $http.serverRequest (http:localhost:8080/test/lib/angular/angular.js:7652:16)
    at wrappedCallback (http:localhost:8080/test/lib/angular/angular.js:11042:81)
    at wrappedCallback (http:localhost:8080/test/lib/angular/angular.js:11042:81)
    at http:localhost:8080/test/lib/angular/angular.js:11128:26
    at Scope.$eval (http:localhost:8080/test/lib/angular/angular.js:12069:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http:localhost:8080/test/lib/angular/angular.js:11898:31) angular.js:9505
```

What is the issue? How can I fix it?

Thanks and Regards,
George

Comment: it means that the json results is wrong, there is a syntax issue with the json

Comment: I am getting following  Error: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': '' is not a valid HTTP header field value.

Comment: i think you need to remove the id, maybe also the token just leave the content-type

Comment: Thanks @Laid Livnat. How to send the token and Id to the Webservice? How to Send the Data and the Header confidential Data like id and token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your request, remove the id and token from the headers, leave only content-type, if you want to send cradentials, you can add `withCredentials: true` to the request.

```
$http({
 url     : 'http://l-o-c-a-l-h-o-s-t:8080/dummy',
 method  : 'POST',
 data    : {'id':'1','name':'test'}, 
 headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
 withCredentials: true})
```

you can read about with credntils more in here:

> withCredentials - {boolean} - whether to set the withCredentials flag
>   on the XHR object. See [requests with credentials] https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#section_5